# Reading Excel files using PHP excel reader library

Tags: php, excel

I am using [php excel library](https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/downloads/list)  to read Excel files. The code works fine if the Excel file is located in the project directory but it's not working if the Excel file is located some where else.

The error is shown in the screenshot below.

I found that the problem is because the file address is not propagated properly through a GET request. How can I overcome this?

[image]

Comment: hi, two things. 1. you have a wrong path, 2. you have a wrong permission on the folder or file

Answer (score 0):

use $_FILES['verbal_file']['tmp_name']   instead of $_FILES['verbal_file']['name']  on server side

working fine...